# check if delta table exists on a path or not in databricks

Tags: scala, databricks, delta-lake

I need to delete certain data from a delta-lake table before I load it. I am able to delete the data from delta table if it exists but it fails when the table does not exist.

**Databricks scala code below**

```scala
// create delete statement
val del_ID = "Check_ID =" + "123"

// get delta table from path where data exists
val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, path)

// delete data from delta table
deltaTable.delete(del_ID)
```

The above code works only if the delta data exists on that path otherwise it fails.

**Can someone share an approach where the delete statement is executed if the delta data exists else the delete statement is ignored ?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [DeltaTable's Javadoc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/java/io/delta/tables/DeltaTable.html), you can check that there is a delta table in specified path with the following command:

```
DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, "path/to/table")
```

If the path does not contain delta table or doesn't exist, it will return false. So your code would be:

```
val del_ID = "Check_ID ="+ "123" 
if (DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, path)) {
  DeltaTable.forPath(spark, path).delete(del_ID)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Other way around in python using Spark SQL API:

```
spark.sql(f'describe detail {path}').collect()[0].asDict()['format'] == 'delta'
```

This comes handy when you are not able use the Delta API, as in databricks-connect.

Comment: I like this method, because it also works with a given table name instead of an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the table exists in the information_schema of the catalog. The result of this query (see below result_df) would be either an empty table (if such a table doesn't exist), or a table with a row. After that you apply the logic with the "if" - if the result_df is not empty - do something, drop the table, etc, otherwise do something else.

If you use the code below directly, don't forget to replace "some_catalog_name" with your catalog name and "the table you check if exists" with your table name.

```
result_df = spark.sql(f'SELECT * FROM some_catalog_name.information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = "the table you check if exists"')

if not (result_df.isEmpty()):
    do something ...
else:
    do something else ...
```